# Change file property in team foundation server 2010 via Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I need to be able to change the "ANSI NULL" property of a file in Team Foundation Server 2010 via Powershell:

```
cls
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
}

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = get-tfsserver "http://tfsserver.com"

$items = Get-TfsItemProperty -Server $tfs -Item "$/databaseproject/Database/trunk/Database/Stored Procedures" -Recurse | where{$_.ItemType -eq "File"}
foreach($item in $items)
{
    #i'm stuck on how to get/change the file item properties
}
```

Essentially, I want to change the ANSI NULLS property of the .sql file in TFS from ON to OFF.  I've got about 60 of them to change.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is an ANSI NULL property on the object that Get-TfsItemProperty outputs and even if it did have such a property you wouldn't be able to change it. Get-TfsItemProperty creates a local data object from information retrieved from the server.  It is immutable i.e. all of its properties only have getters (not setters).

This property is more likely a setting captured in some file (.dbschema??).  In that case, I would normally suggest you check out that file, modify the setting and check it back in.  However, I ran across [this Q&A that might help](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/to-set-quoted_identifier-ansi_nulls-53381.aspx).  Specifically look at answers 8 & 9.  Answer 8 implies there might be a bug where even changing the setting doesn't help.  Answer 9 has some suggested workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Keith!  From what I can see, no, there is none.    I was hoping I was missing something.  It's a .sql file in a dbproject, and each stored proc file (*.sql) has an ANSI Nulls property

Comment: Okay, trying this again:  Thanks Keith!  From what I can see, no, there is none.    I was hoping I was missing something.  It's a .sql file in a dbproject, and each stored proc file (*.sql) has an ANSI Nulls property.  It looks like generic tfs item properties, to which the ANSI Nulls would not apply.  Here's a picture to show what I mean:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/hh4i08mnmd0ihs5/Cap.PNG

Comment: You would need to find which file stores that setting. Perhaps it is in the project file?  If it isn't easy to find, use SysInternals ProcMon to monitor file system activity when you change the setting.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks Keith.  I will mark yours as the answer (even though it isn't the answer I wanted to hear  ;)

Comment: Actually, I'm going to leave it hang out unanswered for a bit to see if anyone chimes in.  I'm 99.9% sure your answer is the correct one, but I'm throwing a hail mary anyway.  ;)

Comment: No problem.  While I know PowerShell and TFS fairly well, I'm a noob when it comes to databases.